# Set a view field to use Full HTML

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, field

Ok so I don't seem to be getting much help on the Drupal forums so I thought I might try here. Here is my scenario. I have built a drupal module that connects to a database and retrieves data. This part has been done successfully. I can get every piece of data that I need from this database. One of the fields that I am retrieving contains HTML code in it. So naturally I want this code to be displayed properly in my field for the view when it pulls the data.

I have asked questions over on the drupal forums and one person recommended that I use the handler below.

**A section of my drupal module that needs to implement Full HTML**

```
//This is breaking the site.
$data['Jobs']['JobHTML'] = array(
  'title' => t('Job HTML'),
  'help' => t('A pre-formatted job.'),
  'field' => array(
  'handler' => 'views_handler_area_text',
   ),
);
```

This handler however breaks and throws the following exception.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debug...
Path...
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: Fatal error: Call to undefined method 
views_handler_area_text::pre_render() 
in sites\all\modules\views\includes\view.inc 
on line 1162
```

If anyone has any insight into Drupal views please let me know as I have been wrestling with this for quite some time. Please remember that my module is working and I am pulling and displaying data from it. I just need the data to be formatted correctly when it comes through.

**EDIT**

Example of a field with 'handler' => 'views_handler_area_text'

```
ID    Title             ActivityHTML

1111  MyCustomActivity  <p>This has test content in it. <br /> Here is another line of content</p>
```

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1807708 : instructions to write a custom handler for this

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `area handler` for a field.  Use `views_handler_field_text` instead.

Comment: When I try this it shows me the content in the field. However, it shows me html tags + the content. What I am going for is to get the HTML tags utilized in the view. So if its a <br /> add a new line don't show <br />